# AWS ssh requesting password

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, passwords, system-administration

I have just set up a new cloudLinux AMI instance on AWS and have correctly ssh in from my terminal with the key pair. However it is requesting a password for the instance which I have not set. Any thoughts on how to ascertain this password so I can get into the server?

ssh -i  root@<--Instance Public IP -->

terminal requests password: ?????

Comment: Probably the key pair you are using is invalid or it does not correspond to the root user. You could add the -v flag to know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of AMI's don't let you log in as root. Try logging in as the user "ec2-user". 
ssh -i mypem.pem ec2-user@my-ip